# Groovy: Creating XML nodes using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy

I am able to find the nodes using xpath in Groovy. at the same time would like to create xml hierarchy using the same xpath. For example:

```
"/*[local-name()='tag1']/*[local-name()='tag2'][@att1='attValue1'][@att2='attValue2']"
```

with this path i should be able to find the node if exists otherwise it should create missing tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which library are you using? XPath is just for querying. You can split the query in two parts, one to select the parent and one to select the actual nodes. Then you can query for the parent (that must exists before) and then query for matching children. If the children are not found you can create them and set the correct parent.

Comment: I was looking for any pre-defined library which does same thing for me. since xpath goes very generic, writing logic for all the combinations is going take considerable amount of time and testing effort.

Comment: I see, but I don't think there is a library that's capable to do what you want. XPath doesn't define nodes completely (e.g. they could have additional attributes, you could query on substrings, the number of nodes is not defined...)